# Fails to import VM with "ClientError: Unknown OS/Missing OS files" using Ubuntu OVA

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I created a linux (Ubuntu Server 16.04) based VM and tried exporting and converting it to AWS EC2.
This is the error that I received -

```
{
"ImportImageTasks": [
    {
        "Description": "ova_test",
        "ImportTaskId": "import-ami-0ecd1033b509f59b2",
        "SnapshotDetails": [
            {
                "DiskImageSize": 34091646464.0,
                "Format": "VMDK",
                "Status": "completed",
                "UserBucket": {
                    "S3Bucket": "vm_bucket",
                    "S3Key": "linux.ova"
                }
            }
        ],
        "Status": "deleted",
        "StatusMessage": "ClientError: Unknown OS / Missing OS files."
    }
]
}
```

What can be the problem here?

This is the containers.json -

```
[
  {
    "Description": "ova_test",
    "Format": "ova",
    "UserBucket": {
        "S3Bucket": "vm_bucket",
        "S3Key": "linux.ova"
    }
}]
```

Comment: I never did this myself, so maybe I am totally wrong, but aren't you mixing `OVA` and `VMDK` format? The file is `OVA`, but on import task it is specified as `VMDK`.

Comment: No.. The specified format is OVA.. But this is what the status shows

Comment: Share your `disk-containers` file when you created the import task.

Comment: @Azize I've added the containers json

Comment: Just to confirm, are you sure you exported the image as OVA and not as VMDK? For some reason it is understanding the file as VMDK, even though you specified the format as OVA.

Comment: @Azize Yeah, the file is, ".ova" (Because I can open it with tar and see that the VMDK is inside)